# why Prompt windows credentials after SSO Microsoft Account verification?

Tags: sharepoint-server, ssl, azure-ad, sso, trusted-identity-provider

I have configured SSO on Premises SharePoint 2010 with Azure AD. Following are the steps i have performed:

1: Created SSO SharePoint Application Azure Portal

2: Configured Azure Portal for SSO by giving SharePoint on premises URL, URN etc

3: Created Identity Provider in SharePoint using Power Shell script

4: Created user in Azure AD

5: Provide full control in SharePoint to newly created user on Azure AD

When user hit SharePoint server url, it redirects to Microsoft login which is fine. I enter credentials with Microsoft domain it validates perfectly. After this i get prompt to enter windows credentials. :(

I have to disable this prompt it only needs to be logged in via Microsoft account. what i am doing wrong?

Regards;

Sabeeh MCP and MCSE